# Django reportlab insert pagebreak html-side

Tags: django, pdf, reportlab

I'm trying to insert a pagebreak after a table in a pdf I'm generating with reportlab, I'm using the following function to generate the pdf:

```
def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict):
  template = get_template(template_src)
  context = Context(context_dict)
  html  = template.render(context)
  result = StringIO.StringIO()
  pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO.StringIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), dest=result, link_callback=fetch_resources)
  if not pdf.err:
    return result.getvalue()
  return HttpResponse('We had some errors<pre>%s</pre>' % escape(html))
def fetch_resources(uri, rel):
    return os.path.join(MEDIA_ROOT, uri.replace(MEDIA_URL, ""))
```

I'm calling the function from a view this way:

```
@login_required(login_url=reverse('accounts:login_box'))
def quote_pdf(request, quote_id):
    data_pdf = {}
    quote = get_object_or_404(Quote, id=quote_id)
    data_pdf['pagesize'] = 'letter'
    data_pdf['quote'] = quote
    pdf = render_to_pdf('rents/quote_pdf.html', data_pdf)
    return HttpResponse(pdf, mimetype='application/pdf')
```

And this is my template (quote_pdf.html)

```
{% load humanize compress verbatim %}

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Cotización No. {{ quote.id }} Flasherz.co/alquiler</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        @page {
            size: {{ pagesize }};
            margin: 1cm;
            @frame footer {
                -pdf-frame-content: footerContent;
                bottom: 0cm;
                margin-left: 0cm;
                margin-right: 0cm;
                height: 0cm;
            }
        }
    </style>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            font-size: 12px;
            line-height: 13px;
        }
        div#pdf-header {
            display: block;
        }
        div#pdf-header h2 {
            display: block;
            text-align: center;
            font-weight: normal;
            line-height: 35px;
            font-size: 18px;
        }
        div#pdf-quote-info {
            display: block;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
        }
        p {
            margin: 0;
        }
        table {
            border-top: 1px solid #eee;
        }
        table td, table th {
            border-right: 1px solid #eee;
            border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
            padding: 5px;
            border-left: 1px solid #eee;
        }
        table .price {
            text-align: right;
        }
        table th {
            padding: 5px 0;
            font-size: 13px;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            color: black;
            text-align: left;
            background-color: #eee;
            padding-left: 5px;
        }
        table p.description {
            color: #555;
            font-size: 11px;
        }
        table#quote-info {
            border: none;
        }
        table#quote-info td, table#quote-info th {
            border: none;
            padding: 0;
        }
        table td.quantity {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="pdf-header">
    <div style="width: 100%; text-align: center;">
        <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/quotes-logo.jpeg" alt="Flasherz.co Alquiler" width="600" height="126" />
        <div style="display: block; text-align: center; margin: 10px 0;">
            <h2>Cotización No. {{ quote.id }}, {{ quote.client_name }}</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="pdf-quote-info">
    <table id="quote-info" width="70%" border="none" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td width="25%">Fecha:</td>
            <td width="75%">{{ quote.created|date:'l j' }} de {{ quote.created|date:'F' }} de {{ quote.created|date:'Y' }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% if quote.client_name %}
            <tr>
                <td>Cliente:</td>
                <td>{{ quote.client_name }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endif %}
        {% if quote.client_email %}
            <tr>
                <td>Correo:</td>
                <td>{{ quote.client_email }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endif %}
        {% if quote.client_address %}
            <tr>
                <td>Dirección:</td>
                <td>{{ quote.client_address }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endif %}
        {% if quote.client_phone %}
            <tr>
                <td>Teléfono:</td>
                <td>{{ quote.client_phone }}</td>
            </tr>
        {% endif %}
        <tr>
            <td>Cantidad de días:</td>
            <td>{{ quote.rental_days }}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="pdf-quote-table">
    <table id="quote-table" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        {% for category in quote.categories.all %}
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="4" class="category-header">{{ category.category.name }}</th>
            </tr>
            {% for item in category.items.all %}
                <tr>
                    <td class="quantity" width="10%">
                        <p>{{ item.quantity }}</p>
                    </td>
                    <td class="name" width="50%">
                        <p class="name">{{ item.name }}</p>
                        {% if item.content %}<p class="description">{{ item.content }}</p>{% endif %}
                    </td>
                    <td class="price" width="20%">
                        <p>${{ item.price|intcomma }}</p>
                    </td>
                    <td class="price total-price" width="20%">
                        <p>${{ item.total_price|intcomma }}</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        {% endfor %}
        <tbody id="others">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4" class="category-header">Seguro del 10%</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="quantity"></td>
            <td class="name">Seguro 10%</td>
            <td class="price"></td>
            <td class="price total-price">
                <p>${{ quote.get_insurance_price|intcomma }}</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
        {% if quote.discount %}
            <tbody id="others">
            <tr>
                <th colspan="4" class="category-header">Descuento</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="quantity">
                </td>
                <td class="name">Descuento</td>
                <td class="price"></td>
                <td class="price total-price">
                    <p>${{ quote.discount|intcomma }}</p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        {% endif %}
        <tbody id="totals">
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4" class="category-header">Total</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="fake" colspan="2"></td>
            <td class="name">Subtotal</td>
            <td class="price">
                <p>${{ quote.get_subtotal|intcomma }}</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="fake" colspan="2"></td>
            <td class="name">Total días</td>
            <td class="price">
                <p>${{ quote.get_total_days|intcomma }}</p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="fake" colspan="2"></td>
            <td class="name">Total</td>
            <td class="price">
                <p><strong>${{ quote.get_total|intcomma }}</strong></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know the way to insert a pagebreak after the table to insert the "terms and conditions" in the next page.

Also I have a problem with the images in the pdf, no one is appearing when rendered.

Thanks for helping me

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've found the correct method to do it, I needed to insert a few specific styles in the  of my pdf

```
<style type="text/css">
    @page {
        size: {{ pagesize }};
        margin: 1cm;
        @frame footer {
            -pdf-frame-content: footerContent;
            bottom: 0cm;
            margin-left: 0cm;
            margin-right: 0cm;
            height: 0cm;
        }
    }
    .page-break{
        page-break-after: always;
    }
</style>
```

Then put a  element with .page-break class in where you want to have a page break in your pdf.

Answer (score 19):

From what I've learned in [Pisa's documentation](http://xhtml2pdf.appspot.com/static/pisa-en.html) (and [this forum post](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/xhtml2pdf/RllJjS1YYgM)), you can use standard CSS tags like `page-break-after` and `page-break-before`. Pisa also has some of it's own tags, like `pdf:nextpage`. To use this, simply insert the following code block where you would like the page break (the div's are necessary so Pisa's HTML5 parser doesn't try to interpret them):

```
<div>
    <pdf:nextpage /> 
</div>
```

Comment: Worked for me - quick and easy - thanks. I built it into a Jinja template

Answer (score 3):

I had no luck with the css method.

Just insert this bit of code in your template.html wherever you want a page break. It works for me. I'm not sure, but I think it has to be in a div.

```
<div> 
   <pdf:nextpage /> 
</div>
```